# mousedown propagation on siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coffeescript

I have a div with several img-Objects with position:absolute like so:

```
<div>  
    <img>  
    <img>  
    <img>  
    <img>  
</div>
```

Now when one of the image's mousedown handler is called, the event will only bubble down, ignoring the other images, even when they might be behind each other.

```
$('img').mousedown((event) -> if(something) event.stopPropagation());  
$('div').mousedown(-> alert('event came through'));
```

I tried to nest them to work around this issue, but that didn't work either:

```
<div>  
    <img>    
    <div>  
        <img>  
        <div>  
            <img> 
            ...   
        </div>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

is there any way I can get this to work without manually running a hit-test on every image?

Comment: A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would make this question much clearer and easier to answer.

Comment: @madfriend basically the images represent shapes with a transparent background, and I only want the mousedown event to fire when the shape itself is clicked, not the transparent part of the image. That in itself is not hard to do, but clicking on a transparent part while another image is located in the 'background' will result, as I said, in the click event bubbling directly to the container.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mousedown. propagation on siblings event.targets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811073/mousedown-propagation-on-siblings-event-targets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any way I can get this to work without manually running a hit-test on every image?

I believe it's correct that you have to run a hit-test yourself. `mousedown` only occurs on the front-most element under the mouse pointer, not all elements at those `(x, y)` coordinates.

In practice, this isn't so hard. Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/TrevorBurnham/GBuZz/

In that example, `mousedown` events are captured on the container element and handled like so:

```
$('#container').on 'mousedown', (e) ->
  {pageX, pageY} = e
  $(@).children().each (i) ->
    {top, left} = $(@).offset()
    if top <= pageY <= top + $(@).outerHeight() &&
       left <= pageX <= left + $(@).outerWidth()
      console.log 'collision with box ' + i​
```

Comment: In theory, it's not really hard, yes.
But I need a way to 'cancel' this procedure when a condition is met on an item, going from the foremost to the rearmost in that order. It would have been most elegant to just bubble through the events and cancel the propagation when necessary, otherwise let it bubble up to the 'base' layer.

Comment: The problem is that events can bubble from child-to-parent, or they can bubble from front-to-back. The two are mutually exclusive. If you want bubbling logic other than child-to-parent, you have to implement it yourself.

Comment: I see. No other choice but to do the 'collision check' on every object, then, and break if a collision was found. I used your fiddle, added my collision logic and reversed the order to select the front item.